# how to pass generic data type to a method and how to create a propper method for using it?

Tags: java, generics

I want to refactor some of my methods into one method for converting string values into int/float based on method argument. for this matter I have create a method like following :

```
private <T>Number setNumericValue(String value , T type)
{

    value = value.trim();
    if(isNumeric(value))
    {
        if (type instanceof Integer)
            return Integer.parseInt(value);
        if (type instanceof Float)
            return Float.parseFloat(value);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

first off I want to know is my method correct?
and for calling this method how should I use it? I've created something like this but java give me runtime error

```
this.temperatureC = setNumericValue(temperatureC, Float);
```

the error saying : "unable to cast Float to T"

Comment: You don't need your own `isNumeric()` function. `parseInt()`, `parseFloat()` and such will throw a `NumberFormatException`, catch that to return a default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the default value of the appropriate type too:

```
private <T extends Number> T setNumericValue(String value, Class<T> type) {
    value = value.trim();
    if (isNumeric(value)) {
        if (type.isAssignableFrom(Float.class))
            return type.cast(Float.parseFloat(value));
        if (type.isAssignableFrom(Integer.class))
            return type.cast(Integer.parseInt(value));
    } else {
        if (type.isAssignableFrom(Float.class))
            return type.cast(Float.valueOf(0));
        if (type.isAssignableFrom(Integer.class))
            return type.cast(Integer.valueOf(0));
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format(
            "Cannot convert '%s' to %s", value, type.getSimpleName()
    ));
}
```

Your original construct wasn't typesafe, you can't cast a primitive value to `T extends Number`. Java's primitive type wrappers also don't support converting between different number types using `Class.cast`, so you have to do this explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that :

```
private <T extends Number> T setNumericValue(String value , Class<T> type)
{

    value = value.trim();
    if(isNumeric(value))
    {
        if (type.isAssignableFrom(Float.class))
            return type.cast(Float.valueOf(value));
        if (type.isAssignableFrom(Integer.class))
            return type.cast(Integer.valueOf(value));
    }
    return type.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance("0");
}
this.temperatureC = setNumericValue(temperatureC, Float.class);
```

Comment: after changing my return value to what you and Robin says I'll get error for returning type in jre 1.7 the error "cannot convert From int to T"

Comment: @austinpowers That error doesn't occur with this code sample. If you use someone else's suggestion and it doesn't work, edit your post with the code you have and point out where the new error occurs instead of having others trace back through all the various answers and comments to try and figure out what you're referring to.

Comment: @austinpowers Ok, I have correct my answer. I add "type.cast()" and valueOf for correct assign and "type.cast(Integer.valueOf(0))" for the default value (there may be a better solution for defaut value).

Comment: @julienda: Does that even work? Won't `Float.class.cast(Integer.valueOf(0))` just throw a `ClassCastException`?

Comment: @Inerdial you have right. I have change to "type.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance("0");", I you have better solution I take it.

Answer (score 2):

If you change the signature of your method to (and the implementation accordingly)

```
private <T extends Number> T setNumericValue( String value, Class<T> classType)
```

you can call it with

```
this.temperatureC = setNumericValue( temperatureC, Float.class )
```